# Not able to change the theme in Magento

Tags: magento

I am quite new to Magento. I have just downloaded Magento framework and configured in Local Host. I have a theme that i want to use. I have extracted the theme and pasted the content in the root directory where magento has been configured. Now i don't see this theme in the Admin panel.

Please help me in applying the theme. I am using Magento 2.1

Comment: Please describe in details and where have you set theme ? Give snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

The theme configuration was moved.

It can be found in main administration menu:

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

Click on scope you are interested in(probably the first one) and change 'Applied theme'.

In newer version of Magento all design related item moved to :

```
Content-> Design -> Configuration -> Edit
```

Or USE Below:

**Apply a theme**

After you add your theme to the file system, you can apply it to your store. You apply a theme in Admin.

To apply a theme:

1. In Admin, go to Stores > Configuration > Design.
2. In the Store View drop-down field, select the store view where you want to apply the theme.
3. On the Design Theme tab, select your newly created theme in the Design Theme drop-down.
4. Click Save Config.
5. If caching is enabled, clear the cache.
6. To see your changes applied, reload the store front pages.

Comment: if any query, please reply.